# Stop a function until an event occurs

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it was possible to stop the execution of my function until the user clicks on one of the two photos

I tried several techniques but the function continued to run while waiting for the answer

```
<div class="container1">
    <img src="" id='photo1' class="photo1">
    <div class="middle">
        <div id='text1' class="text">Picture 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <img src="" id='photo2' class="photo1">
    <div class="middle">
        <div id='text2' class="text">Picture 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function choix(tabR,tabN){
        globalTempo = 0;
        if (tabR.length == 0){
            tabR.push(tabN);
        }
        else if (tabR.length == 1 ){
            faireChoix(tabN,tabR[0]);
// I want to stop the execution here untill the user click on one picture 
            if (globalTempo == 1 ){
                tampon = [];
                tampon.push(tabN);
                tabR = tampon.concat(tabR);
            }
            else if(globalTempo == 2) {
                tabR.push(tabN);
            }
        } else if (tabR.length > 1 ) {
            faireChoix(tabN,tabR[0]);
            if (globalTempo == 1){
                tabFin = couperTab(tabR,Math.floor(tabR.length/2),tabR.length);
                tabDebut = choix(couperTab(tabR,0,Math.floor(tabR.length/2)),tabN);
            }
            else{
                tabDebut = couperTab(tabR,0,Math.floor(tabR.length/2)+1);
                tabFin = choix(couperTab(tabR,Math.floor(tabR.length/2)+1,tabR.length),tabN);
            }
        }
        return tabR;
    }
```

The function choix is called like that in a loop

```
function tournament(tab){
    res = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i <  tab.length ; i++) {
        res = choix(res,tab[i]);
    }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to order elements

Comment: I'm very rusty on these but sounds like you could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: You can use a promise

Comment: JS is event based; the simple solution is to put the stuff supposed to run after a click in a second function and assign it as click listener. How is `choix` called? In a loop? What's the bigger picture here?

Answer (score 0):

As @Aluan suggests, this can be achieved using promises.

In the example below, `createWait` returns a promise that will be resolved when `ready()` is invoked (in this case on the button click).

```js
// function to help manage waiting for ready method to be called
function createWait() {
  let callback;
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    callback = resolve;
  });
  
  function wait() {
    return promise;
  }
  
  wait.ready = callback;
  
  return wait;
}

const wait = createWait();

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wait.ready();
});

function choix_promise() {
  console.log('choix_promise step1');
  wait().then(() => {
    console.log('choix_promise step2');
  });
}
choix_promise();

async function choix_asnyc() {
  console.log('choix_asnyc step1');
  await wait();
  console.log('choix_asnyc step2');
}
choix_asnyc();
```

```html
<button>ready</button>
```

You then need to update your function to execute bit after the *wait* with a callback to `Promise.then`.

Alternatively, if you can use `async`/`await`, you could simply `await` the promise.

```
async function choix_asnyc() {
  console.log('choix_asnyc step1');
  await wait(); // await the promise here
  console.log('choix_asnyc step2');
}
```

Comment: Am I mistaken, or can you remove the first line, "let ready = false;"

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to above, but somewhat reduced:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {stopWaiting();});

let stopWaiting= function(){};

function startWaiting() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    stopWaiting = resolve;
  });
}

console.log('choix_promise_1');
startWaiting().then(() => {
   console.log('choix_promise_2');
});
```

```html
<button id="b1">Stop Waiting</button>
```

Comment: Suggest making use of StackOverflow's code snippets when possible. It makes it easier for others to test and observe the answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have gone back and done so.  Thanks.